# Rolling back backwards incompatible database migrations

Tags: database, database-migration, rollback, backwards-compatibility

This is a question unrelated to any specific technology. Let's suppose we have an application that is using a database to store information, and that we're using some tool to execute database migrations between new application releases (e.g. [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org)).

If the db change done by the SQL script is backwards compatible, there are no issues when needing to roll back to a previous version. *However*, every now and then, some backwards incompatible changes need to be applied (pretty much anything changing the schema - add/remove/modify a column/table etc., but also rewriting the values in rows). What are the options/suitable solutions to this problem? The ones I have identified are as follows:

- [Split the migration into five parts](https://java.jiderhamn.se/2017/08/22/non-backwards-compatible-sql-database-migration/). This seems like a bulletproof solution to me, but it involves many more releases. This might be very problematic for a company that doesn't release that often.
- Before every release, perform a database snapshot and restore it in case of rollback. This leads to a data loss, though, and also is problematic in case of rolling updates and in case the database is very large and the backup takes a significant amount of time.
- For every migration script, create a rollback script. This is however not possible in all cases (e.g. when changing the values in some rows).
- Don't do any backwards incompatible changes. While I think it's possible to avoid them in many cases, I don't see it possible to avoid them completely.

I don't think there's a silver bullet to this problem, but perhaps there is a more suitable solution that I didn't think of.

Comment: What's the problem with the backup? You have one anyway. And if it's a big database, the backup is incremental allowing for point-in-time recovery as well.

Comment: Well, with every restore of backup, this leads to data loss (which is probably acceptable risk when you already need to roll back). It's definitely a solution, what I'm asking is whether there is a better, generally more suitable approach I am missing, probably in terms of "how do I write my migrations so that I can roll them back". Also, good point with incremental backups, that effectively solves the downside I've listed in my original post.